# Как опустить кнопку в низ экрана и отцентрировать её внизу?

Tags: android, xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button
<- - - >
android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
< - - ->
/>
```